# How can I install Wine without Internet?

Tags: installation, wine, offline

I don’t have Internet, and I use Internet through a USB modem device which is supported in only Windows, so I tried to install Wine to run that software, and I downloaded Wine but it says

```
dependency is not satisfiable: libgettextpo0
```

What to do?

Comment: Hi, you tried a wine deb  package or to build from source? apart from that, could you specify your modem, perhaps there s a native linux driver (somewhere in the net ;o))

Comment: You can download Wine 1.3.30 offline installer from [here](http://www.linuk.web.id/2011/10/wine-1330-offline-installer-ubuntu-1110.html) and take a look at the attached 'readme' file on how to install it, basically you'll just run the install script with `sudo sh install.sh` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be the only dependency you will need, you can find the libgettextpo0 from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libgettextpo0). Double click on the file in Ubuntu and click install. You need to do this before you install wine.

On this page you can also search for packages so if you see you have more dependencies you might have to go back to this page. Type the name of the dependency in the search box, download it and repeat.